# "Judges" or "Justices"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Should one use the words "judges" or "justices" when referring to multiple members of constitutional or supreme courts of countries without English as their native language ?

Comment: [This wisegeek post](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-the-difference-between-a-justice-and-a-judge.htm) explains the difference rather well, I think.

Comment: @J.R. Generally, but since the Q. refers to specific courts, the explanation is inadequate imho. Just with the _SCOTUS_, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_Justice_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States) showcases discrepancies in the normative instruments' text, as well as the terminology used with the composition changing over time. The task may require analysis of the source [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judge) and legal system involved, depending on the target audience. I'm no NS but I don't think "my friend is a justice" is usual AmE w.o chief or "of the peace"?

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres - Yes, I meant to say, that post explains the _general_ difference rather well. :^) It's a good start, but not a definitive answer (which is why my comment wasn't accompanied by a close vote). You make some excellent points – perhaps you could flesh them out in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The plural of *'Judge'* and *'Justice'* are *'Judges'* and *'Justices'* respectively. Neither of them are incorrect. And the plural forms of those nouns  are valid in countries that has English as the native language too.